# How to increase CSS specification in MUI makeStyle for styled component to override the root style?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I am new in react world, I'm trying to use MUI makeStyle to override the existing style, eg : fontWeight:'bold' not working even with !important. thank you for any suggestion.

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
const tableStyle = makeStyles(() => ({
  CustomTable:{
    borderCollapse: 'separate',
    borderSpacing: '0px 8px',
    paddingInline: '8px',
  },
  CustomTableCell_1:{
    backgroundColor: '#F7EDF4',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    borderTopLeftRadius: '100px',
    borderBottomLeftRadius: '100px',
    paddingBlock: '16px',
    paddingInline: '24px',
  },
    CustomTableCell_2:{
    backgroundColor: '#F7EDF4',
    borderTopRightRadius: '100px',
    borderBottomRightRadius: '100px',
    paddingBlock: '16px',
    paddingInline: '24px',
  },
}));
export default tableStyle;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can uses custom styles using **makeStyles**

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
```

create a function using makeStyles

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  // Your custom styles go here
}));
```

And you can apply like this,

```
function Comp() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Button className={classes.root}>
      My Custom Button
    </Button>
  );
}
```

Or you can also use sx attribute to apply custom css
try fontWeight: 'bolder' or "600"

Comment: Thanks Noman, I did this, but the problem is in the CSS specificity, how we can make it higher with makeStyle ( ! important not working also),  when using it, overriding the root classes is not working. with SX ad inline style it works fine.